# Why my console input is not terminating. if i remove the code countSwaps(a,size) then console input terminating otherwise not

Tags: java, arrays

my loop is not terminating when i use this code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[] a = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
    countSwaps(a,size);
}
```

but when i removie the last line of my code loop get terminated otherwise not.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    int[] a = new int[size];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    }
}
```

the fucction definition is:

```
private  static void countSwaps(int[] a, int size) {
    int temp,count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size-1;i++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array is sorted in"+count+"swaps.");
    System.out.println("First Element:"+a[0]);
    System.out.println("Last Element:"+a[a.length-1]);

}
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show the code of countSwaps which is likely to cause your program not to terminate.

Comment: Inner loop is `for(int j=0;j<size-1;i++)` - you're incrementing `i` instead of `j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
for(int j=0;j<size-1;i++){
```

You are looping the j, but increasing i++

change to be:

```
private  static void countSwaps(int[] a, int size) {
    int temp,count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<size-1;j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=temp;
                ++count;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Array is sorted in"+count+"swaps.");
    System.out.println("First Element:"+a[0]);
    System.out.println("Last Element:"+a[a.length-1]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop never increments `j`.